# Phonegap Plugin Development: how to add Phonegap plugin dependency in plugin.xml?

Tags: plugins, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I developed a new plugin for phonegap framework but it depends on phonegap [Device](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device) plugin as a prerequisite to work, so my question is how to add device plugin as a dependency on my plugin.xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare dependencies using  tag that allows you to specify other plugins on which the current plugin depends.

For Device plugin you could add this line in your plugin.xml:

`<dependency id="org.apache.cordova.device" url="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device.git"  />`

For more parameters you can use with dependency element check info at:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification

Cheers!